# why is my flutter app sending unlimited request

Tags: android, asynchronous, flutter, future

while trying to get the list of countries from my api, my code is sendig unlimited request to the server when i call the function one time. here is the flutter code

```
 Future<dynamic> listePays() async{

http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl+"api_pays", headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
var resp = json.decode(response.body);
return resp;
}
```

i want to send just one request and work with the answers. ihave tried removing Future but i get the same issue

i call the function like this:

```
     getPays() async {
         Functions().listePays().then((data) async {

          pays = data;
          setState(() {});


             });


          }
```

Comment: You need to provide the snippet of how you call listePays

Comment: you probably calling getPays() on your build() method without a condition, so each time the widget state is changed -> rebuilt, your function is called